# Getting KeyError:'Database' while running init_db() as detailed in step 3 of Flask tutorial

Tags: python, flask

Similar question has already been asked but solutions didn't work for me.
 File structure is like this

```
c\flaskr
     \flaskr.py,schema.sql,flaskr.db
```

In code, I have set this:

```
DATABASE = '.\\flaskr\\flaskr.db'
```

I have also tried this

```
DATABASE = 'C:\flaskr\flaskr.db'
```

But when I run from flaskr import init_db: init_db(), I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
init_db()
  File "C:\flaskr\flaskr.py", line 21, in init_db
with closing(connect_db()) as db:
  File "C:\flaskr\flaskr.py", line 17, in connect_db
return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
KeyError: 'DATABASE'
```

what is going on? How to resolve this. (sqlite3 is in built with Python)

```
# all the imports
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, \
 abort, render_template, flash
# configuration
DATABASE = '.\\flaskr\\flaskr.db'
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'development key'
USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'default'

# create our little application :)
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_envvar('FLASKR_SETTINGS', silent=True)

def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])

from contextlib import closing
def init_db():
    with closing(connect_db()) as db:
        with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()
```

Comment: please post your complete code

Comment: where is your app instance created, better show me code

Answer (score 0):

You have missed this one,

```
# create our little application :)
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
```

Comment: I added the missed line. Now I am getting different OperationalError: unable to open database file.
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(__name__)
    app.config.from_envvar('FLASKR_SETTINGS', silent=True)

Now what?

Comment: But I introduced the correct database path as you can see.

Comment: I think permission problem